# Specific Question not Showing Number of Close Votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

Generally when there are one or more votes to close a question, the number of votes are shown like this

close (1)

For [a specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765839/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure) that I voted to close, I happened to notice that there is no vote count (there should be at least 1 vote, mine).

When I click "close", the close question dialog informs me that I have already voted to close the question.  I do see *close (n)* for other questions that have a vote or more to close.

Bug?

Answer (score 8):

The question was [closed and then reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11765839/revisions). The close dialog is informing you that you can't vote to close that post, because you had done so previously. No one has cast a close vote on that question since it was reopened, which is why the close link doesn't display the vote count.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  Interestingly, it's been closed again and has 1 vote to reopen again.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the debate over whether or not it should be open has [made its way to Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141952/moderator-closing-a-question-twice-second-opinion).