# What should I do when people try to close a valid question as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

I have a question on Stack Overflow asking why [JavaScript still runs after being disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935664/javascript-still-runs-after-being-disabled)

I thought it was a programming-specific question but it has received 3 close votes now.

To quote the FAQ, we should ask questions about:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

What should I do to preserve the question and get a proper answer (there's still none as of now) instead of getting it closed? And does the presence of close-votes prevent a question from getting seen? The view count has stopped for quite a while.

**EDIT:** A moderator has closed this question twice and locked it. Can someone kindly suggest a better site to ask this question?

Comment: At least make your question self-contained. It should not rely on other questions our outside resources.

Comment: @Bart It isn't. I put that in after people try to close it.

Comment: You are asking about undefined behavior - what happens to JS when it gets disabled by the user while running. It is browser/implementation dependent, and you didn't supply the details.

Comment: @Oded The details are in the fiddle. You have an example to see what is going on and all the relevant codes. I have a summary of the functions used in the question.

Comment: "The details are in the fiddle"...well, that's wrong. The details should be in the question.

Comment: One close question is not the end of the world. Try to be part of the community and understand what the rest think and try to close it - after you understand that, you may change it (or not change it and just accept it).

Comment: That's part of the problem. A link to jsfiddle is a nice _extra_ to a self contained question - if you had posted all the relevant code as well...

Comment: @Oded I didn't want to make this question too long to read. Maybe I should now.

Comment: @Oded: Edited to include the relevant code from the fiddle.

Comment: Even if someone says "yes, it's a loophole" it's still loophole **in the browser itself**, in the way it's handling JavaScript. Nothing we, as programmers, can do and it should be addressed by the developers of each browser exposing such behavior. Personally I'm not flagging your question but can understand why it's flagged.

Comment: That's a good thing to strive for, but a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is probably best.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the info.

Comment: It does look like a much better question now. If it were closed I would likely vote to reopen.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Part of my question is if that if that "loophole" could be exploited to do something useful (not harmful), or if we should alert the developer of the browsers to fix it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for your kind understanding.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I do need your help here. The question is closed now.

Comment: @Oded The question is indeed closed now. I have edited it to reflect the situation and explain the reasoning behind such a question. Can you please kindly have a look and determine if it should be reopened? Thanks.

Comment: The community has decided. The issue is a browser issue and the answers you have gotten reflect that. There is no programming trick to employ, hence the question got closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Oded Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Editing a [lecture](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14935664/14) into your question is against the site's policies and was just really not a good idea. You were already discussing it on Meta.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Alright then. I kind of see this post as _controversial_: 7 upvotes and 6 downvotes. Maybe people have very different opinion on this issue. It's tough when it comes to judge whether something is off-topic or not. But I hope people would express their opinion by casting upvotes and downvotes.  Downvotes are for bad questions. Off-topic close votes are for off-topic questions. I hope Will would share his opinion on how off-topic this question is. I am not into reopening this again, but I hope to have his response, and possibly some suggestions on a better place to ask this.

Comment: @Bart [Moderator closing a question twice. Second opinion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141952/moderator-closing-a-question-twice-second-opinion) Consider editing that question as well?

Comment: @Bart Maybe have a glance and see if that is similar to this?

Comment: @Antony If you think that question should be edited, by all means suggest an edit. I can't handle them all.

Comment: @Bart No I am suggesting not to edit this at all. It's nothing personal. Just that he happens to be the one who closed it twice so asking for his opinion would be logical.

Comment: @Bart Can you help out then? What can I do about this (not being able to ask the moderator who locked a question)?

Comment: What do you want me to do? I can't suggest a better site, if that's what you looking for.

Comment: @Bart So this question is off-topic on SO but yet there is no better site for it. Oh well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Note: **I** can't suggest a better site. Perhaps someone else has a great idea. But perhaps there is none. That would be entirely possible.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations, it's an off-topic question!

Please excuse my plumply answer, but I'm a little bit tired of dancing around the cake. So, let's get to the core, the FAQ:

- a specific programming problem -> Kind of...
- a software algorithm -> Nope
- software tools commonly used by programmers -> Nada
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession -> Not really...

So, that's 0.5 out of 4 (that's your score in the "Let's check the FAQ game"). Your question is not really well-formed because:

- You dump a lot of code on us
- Give us little to no information what that code is doing
- Provide us with little to no information what you want to achieve
- Provide us with no information about the environment you tested the code in.

Additionally it is off-topic because, even if it shows a bug in a browser where you're able to run JavaScript when it is disabled, it should be reported on the appropriate bug-tracker...or, in a very very very very narrow case, asked on Super User.

Comment: Hey! It was not me to dump you a lot of codes. See who edited my question first!

Comment: @Antony: [JsFiddle and Gist links are even worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code?lq=1)...

Comment: Then how can I properly explain the situation to you without an example to see what's going on?

Comment: @Antony: Well commented code together with the explanations of "Why was this code written/What does it solve", "How it does that", "What it's supposed to do" and "What it actually does".

Comment: Having a working example to experiment on is better than having pages of codes for people to dig through. I actually mentioned quite clearly what the code does.

Comment: @Antony you should have the smallest amount of code that can reliably reproduce the problem in the question. Also, there's the other issues DemonBobby points out in his answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think I have the code that produces just that problem in the question. But is SO the wrong place to ask this question?

Comment: "Additionally it is off-topic because, even if it shows a bug in a browser where you're able to run JavaScript when it is disabled, it should be reported on the appropriate bug-tracker...or, in a very very very very narrow case, asked on Super User."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker But Super User is ["not about programming and software development"](http://superuser.com/faq).