# How off-topic is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

Yesterday I asked why my question on SO was getting closed as off-topic. [The answer given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168064/209357) says it was off-topic because of the following reasons:

> So, let's get to the core, the FAQ:
>
> - a specific programming problem -> Kind of...
> - a software algorithm -> Nope
> - software tools commonly used by programmers -> Nada
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession -> Not really...
>
> So, that's 0.5 out of 4 (that's your score in the "Let's check the FAQ game").

While my question eventually gets reopened, here's what I thought about the "FAQ game":

#### Does a question have to fulfill all of the above or just one of them?

Consider a typical question on JavaScript. Is it

> - a specific programming problem -> Kind of...
> - a software algorithm -> Nope
> - software tools commonly used by programmers -> Nada
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession -> Maybe...

So that's 1 out of 4 (do we have to close it as well?).

<sup>(This question has nothing to do with the particular question I asked before. It is a general discussion on how off-topic does a question have to be in order for it to be considered off-topic, based on the FAQ.)</sup>

Comment: How have you decided what a `typical question on JavaScript` is?

Comment: @Oded Let's say how to delay the execution of a function with Javascript. Programming-specific? ya. Software algorithm? nope. Software tools? No. Answerable? Well I can try.

Comment: Off-topic enough that 5 people with close votes available know it when they see it.

Comment: IMHO 1/4 is enough.

Comment: @Wooble How about the FAQ game?

Comment: @Siva If I can easily search the web for an answer, do I have to ask such a question on SO at all?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression there is an official off-topic 'game'. It's one person's check list to see if something is off-topic. I happen to agree on the checklist, and your question is rather borderline.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No I don't have such an impression. Just that someone interprets the checklist that way that makes me think about how I should properly read the FAQ in order not to get a question closed again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't have to check every one of those.

For example there are perfectly fine questions that are not about software tools.

In my opinion you need:

- one of the first three *and*
- the last one

Also note that those are not The Rules™ (emphasis mine):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but **if your question generally covers …**

Comment: Yeah. I wonder how many questions fits all of them. "generally" makes more sense to me.